# Linux - how to connect from local machine to local server using its public IP

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ip, debian-wheezy

I have dedicated machine (Debian) where are running some servers (CS:GO, but it doesn't matter). I need to connect to them from this machine using their public IPs instead of local IPs. Machine is behind router. I don't see any problem to connect to them using their public IPs, but it doesn't work -- their are unreachable. I have also tried `nmap -p 27018 <public IP>`:

```
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-03-20 18:05 CET
Nmap scan report for <public IP>
Host is up (0.00043s latency).
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
27018/tcp closed unknown
```

And with local IP `nmap -p 27018 10.20.30.100`:

```
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-03-20 18:06 CET
Nmap scan report for main (10.20.30.100)
Host is up (0.000057s latency).
PORT      STATE SERVICE
27018/tcp open  unknown
```

**Should I search the problem inside router or this dedicated machine?**

Thanks for help!

Comment: Seems like the router doesn't forward port 27018 to your debian machine, so have a look at the router first.

Comment: Hmm but this machine is normally accesible from outside (people are playing on this game server). But the route inside-outside-inside is forbidden.

Comment: Ok, but that is another port right? Can you reach the debian machine as an external machine (inside-outside-inside) on the game port?

Comment: EDITED: Public port is 27018 and local port is also 27018. I can reach the router in front of the machine using `ping <public IP>` from the machine itself.

Comment: So everyone outside of your network can reach the debian machine on port 27018, but your local machine can not reach it using its public IP. I still suspect it to be a router issue, what kind of router do you have?

Comment: Exactly what you said. Router is also Linux machine, I have to ask the administrator for configuration.

Comment: See if you have NAT loopback set to off, as per the info here: http://help.screenconnect.com/Cannot_access_external_IP_address_from_LAN